# Meteor version1.7.0.5 error - cannot fine module '../lib/utils.js' after updating app to latest version

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteorite

meteor version - 1.9.2

Update my meteor app to verison 1.7.0.5 , backend is running fine but getting below error in frontend.

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is about 1.9.2? I think the latest Meteor version is around 1.7.x, do you maybe refer to a specific package?

Comment: Also if you want to get better SEO for you post it is always a good method to post the error stack as formatted code instead of an image. Also will potential helpers benefit by an improved readability of your post.

Comment: Using relative paths for imports is not always a good idea. Personally I like to use absolute paths, as in `import '/imports/lib/utils.js'`.

Comment: @Jankapunkt meteor show meteor giving output -  Package: meteor@1.9.2

Comment: That's the core package. To get the Meteor version you need to enter `meteor version`

Comment: Have you tried to remove `node_modules/` and `.meteor/local/` and rebuild the app?

Comment: tried this , same issue